# disable theme style of angular material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using angular material 1.1.0-RC1 and I got this overriding all of my anchor styles with the pink colour (Default theme styles). Is there any way to disable theme styles?
Please Help in disabling theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have disable all css coming from material
using this code snippet in my app.js module file

```
app.constant("$MD_THEME_CSS","");
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable default theme of `angularjs` by writing below code in `app.js` file

```
app.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
  $mdThemingProvider.setDefaultTheme('none');
});
```